# Windows service Bus evaluation

Tags: wcf, servicebus

My management is evaluating non-Azure Microsoft Windows Service Bus (Azure is out of consideration for security reasons). It will be used to setup topic/subscription model with a number of WCF services with `netMessagingBinding` that we building, so I just have a few basic questions about that.

1. Are there any specific hardware requirements like dedicated server, dedicated database etc. for WSB to run in production environment?
2. It's easy to configure WCF service to listen on a specific topic subscription. Is there any way for WCF service to listen to multiple subscriptions?

Appreciate the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can install the service components and the databases all on one server (that is the default). However, for a number of reasons, we installed the services on a dedicated app server and then created the Service bus databases on an existing database server. The install package allows you to specify a different db server.  Check [this article for the minimum server requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj714803%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)
2. Yes you can get one WCF service to listen to multiple subscriptions. You would need to create two (or more) *System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost* instances and then run them inside one process. For example we had one windows service running two ServiceHost's.  Each host listened at a different queue and therefore implemented a different contract. This meant where queues were logically grouped we didn't need a new windows service per queue. You could do the same with subscriptions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the link. Management wants to go with High Availability Architecture. Just curious, which version of WSB are you using - 1.0 or 1.1 and what is the difference?

Comment: We started developing with 1.0 and then during the project 1.1 came out, so we went with the latest. We didnt do a big comparison exercise, just took the latest. However, one benefit was that Service Bus Explorer for 1.1 had more functionality.  for example dead letter message replaying, without this we would have had to write our own.

Comment: ps - For high availability you would need more nodes (which your service components lived on) on the farm.   I think 1.1 allows up to 6.

Comment: Thanks. Problem is they don't want to use Azure, so if we stick with 1.1 can we forgo it entirely or would have to some Azure components (configuration I think)?

Comment: no you dont need azure with 1.1. its entirely on prem. when i said more nodes, i meant on prem.

Comment: Oh, thanks, was confused as documentation states it comes with Azure config component.

Answer (score 1):

For question one, you will have to go through the exercise of hardware sizing. the good news is that WCF services can scale vertically, so you can add up servers if there were issues in handling client load.

To do hardware sizing you will have to make an estimate the expected load and then do performance/scalablity testing to figure the load bearing capacity of your serviceBus/services .

you could find a lot of resources for load testing like this one http://seroter.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/testing-out-the-new-appfabric-service-bus-relay-load-balancing/

once you do load testing and come up with the numbers, you can then do sizing using references like this one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310550.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Aren't those links related more to Azure SB then to WSB since Relay in WSB is not supported?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part of your question earlier .But the idea is still the same. You should perf testing. I would try and append the answer with links relevant to WSB